# How to print tax documents?

Tags: printing, pdf

I am trying to print the [GA 500 EZ](http://dor.georgia.gov/sites/dor.georgia.gov/files/related_files/document/TSD/Form/2016_500_EZ_TSD_Short_Individual_Income_Tax_2D.pdf) PDF, and I can't find an application that will print it on ubuntu. When I print I just get pages with "Please print using the BLUE button". Anyone successfully printed the form? I tried Evince and Okular, both couldn't handle the form extra content (which is why I got the error message when printing)

Comment: If download and save the .pdf, and you right-click on it > Open with > Print Preview, do you see the document correctly?

Comment: @M.Becerra That displays correctly, but when I print it I still get the error

Comment: That looks like an advanced PDF with a bunch of forms and stuff. It's probably best viewed in Adobe's official reader. Here's a link to an old Linux version (they've since dropped support for Linux) ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb

Comment: Update - I just tried it with the application I linked above  and it printed fine

Comment: it printed most of the document, but not the first page.... wierd, thanks for the help!

Comment: [Here is a PDF form](http://lodlavki.be/scouts/sites/default/files/documents/Terugbetaling_CM_FitFun.pdf) created with Adobe Indesign 2015 on Mac showing similar printing issues on (X)Ubuntu LTS 16.04. The red filled in fields will not show / remain empty on print. This happens more and more with official filled-in PDF documents. The old Adobe Reader 9.5.5 for Linux works though.

Comment: Opening the PDF page by page with `inkscape` and saving these again as PDF with `inkscape` sometimes does the trick.